# ACF Fields missing after migrate but website works fine

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have recently migrated my DB to a staging environment using string find and replace on the DB to rename the domain. This has made the ACF fields in the CMS to go missing.

[image]

That page should have several fields available. And while the fields are showing in the pages that ACF group is assigned to I can't edit or see them here any more. I can't even create a New ACF group because I can't see the Add Fields box.

The website works fine, the only issue is the fields cannot be edited anymore.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Go to your DB, open table `usermeta`, find your user and delete the field `acf_user_settings`